# Get table columns in SQL Alchemy (1.0.4)

Tags: sqlalchemy

I've realized that in the newest version of **SQLAlchemy** (v1.0.4) I'm getting errors when using the **table.c.keys()** for selecting columns.

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import (Column, Integer, Table, String, PrimaryKeyConstraint)

metadata = MetaData()

table = Table('test', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer,nullable=False),
        Column('name', String(20)),
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )

stmt = select(table.c.keys()).select_from(table).where(table.c.id == 1)
```

In previous versions it used to work fine, but now this is throwing the following errors:

```
sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:3851: SAWarning: Textual column expression 'id' should be explicitly declared with text('id'), or use column('id') for more specificity.
sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:3851: SAWarning: Textual column expression 'name' should be explicitly declared with text('name'), or use column('name') for more specificity.
```

Is there a function for retrieving  all these table columns rather than using a list comprehension like the following? `[text(x) for x in table.c.keys()]`

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can always roll your own.

```python
def all_columns(model_or_table, wrap=text):
    table = getattr(model_or_table, '__table__', model_or_table)
    return [wrap(col) for col in table.c.keys()]
```

then you would use it like

```
stmt = select(all_columns(table)).where(table.c.id == 1)
```

or

```
stmt = select(all_columns(Model)).where(Model.id == 1)
```

Note that in most cases you don't need `select_from`, i.e when you don't actually join to some other table.

Comment: I didn't know it back then, but there is actually no need to use `table.c.keys()`. 
This is all we need: `select([table])`